# Haskell. Find the most frequent number in the list, and if several of them return the maximum of them

Tags: list, haskell

A list of integers is given. Find the most frequently repeated number in it. If there are several such numbers, return the maximum of them.

```
mostFrequent :: [Int] -> Int

--mostFrequent [1,2,2,2,3,3]
--2

--mostFrequent [1,2,2,3,3]
--3
```

I grouped the numbers into a list of pairs and arranged them. But then I do not know how to compare them and output the most repeated and maximum number in the list.

```
mostFrequent :: Ord a => [a] -> [(Int,a)] 
mostFrequent list = map (\l -> (length l, head l)) (group (sort list))
--mostFrequent [1,2,2,3,3]
--[(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

Help me solve this problem.

Comment: See `maximumBy`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy.

Comment: What should `mostFrequent []` be?

Comment: Error "list is empty".

Answer (score 5):

You're absolutely on the right track:

- Sort the inputs so that equal elements become adjacent.
- Group the equal adjacent elements.
- Map each group to a pair consisting of the length of the group and the element.

Then:

- Find the maximum. (The `Ord` instance for pairs give you lexicographic ordering, which is just what you want here.)
- Finally, drop the first component of the greatest pair (the length) by projecting the element.

```
import Data.List (group, sort)

mostFrequent :: [Int] -> Int
mostFrequent ns =
  snd (maximum [ (length ks, head ks) | ks <- group (sort ns) ])
```

```
> mostFrequent [1,2,2,2,3,3]
2

> mostFrequent [1,2,2,3,3]
3
```

---

If *point-free style* is your thing, you can of course also write:

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List (group, sort)

mostFrequent :: [Int] -> Int
mostFrequent = snd . maximum . map (length &&& head) . group . sort
```

Answer (score 1):

calculate maximum frequency and use it to filter. To get the bigger number when two or more have same frequency, you sort the initial list in desc in the first place, so you can pick the first one among them

```
import Data.List

mostFrequent :: [Integer] -> String
mostFrequent [] = "list is empty"
mostFrequent xs = show maxFreqNum
  where 
    sortedGrpBy = fmap (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ groupBy (==) $ reverse $ sort xs
    maxFreq = maximum $ fmap snd sortedGrpBy
    maxFreqNum = fst $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> b == maxFreq) sortedGrpBy
```

output

```
*Main> mostFrequent [1]
"1"
*Main> mostFrequent [1,2,2,2,3,3]
"2"
*Main> mostFrequent [1,2,2,3,3]
"3"
*Main> mostFrequent []
"list is empty"
*Main> mostFrequent [1,2,3,2,3,4,2,3,3]
"3"
```

Comment: Thank! Beautiful solution!